# Make fraction with selection in denominator

Tags: front-end, keyboard

Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> you can make a fraction. If you have selected something it will appear in the numerator.

Does there exist a shortcut to make the selected text appear in the denominator instead?
If not, is it possible to create a shortcut that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Just reverse the output of usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>!

Add the following lines to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["?", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEndTokenExecute["Fraction"],
        FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"],
        NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], Reverse@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[], Placeholder]
    }], 
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic       
  ],
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (<kbd>?</kbd> is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on my keyboard).

This method is fully compatible with brackets, functions, etc. When nothing is selected the cursor is in the numerator. If you prefer the denominator than use the following

```
Item[KeyEvent["?", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEndTokenExecute["Fraction"],
        FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"],
        NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], Reverse@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]],
        NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], "\[Placeholder]", Previous, AutoScroll -> False]
    }], 
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic       
  ],
```

---

Previous method:

```
Item[KeyEvent["?", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute@Module[{den=NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]},
        If[den=={},
           SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Expression];
           den=NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]];
        If[den=={},den="\[Placeholder]"];
        NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],FractionBox["\[Placeholder]",den]];
        SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Previous, Word];
        SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Character]; 
        SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Character]
    ],
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic 
  ],
```

`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic` is important because without it an unevaluated expression is written.

See also: [Customizing Mathematica shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts)

Comment: Seems you were a few seconds quicker :P

Comment: Nice! You could replace the SelectionMove stuff with `Placeholder` as third argument of `NotebookWrite`

Comment: If it works perfectly except one thing: When nothing is selected the cursor should be in the denominator.

Comment: @Tyilo I added the version with the cursor in the denominator.

Comment: @ybeltukov Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using same approach as Rolf [did here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/754/create-shortcut-in-mathematica-for-equal-symbol-aligned-math-cell/829#829)

Putting this in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` does the job:

```
Item[KeyEvent["?", Modifiers -> {Control}],
 FrontEndExecute@With[
  {nb = InputNotebook[]},
  If[NotebookRead@nb === {},
    SelectionMove[nb, All, Expression];
    If[NotebookRead@nb =!= {}, FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"]]
  ];
  NotebookApply[
    nb,
    FractionBox["\[Placeholder]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"],
    Placeholder]
 ], MenuEvaluator->Automatic],
```

Here I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> as it for some reason didn't work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (I tried with "\\" and "Backslash" perhaps it has another name)

Edit: Took keyboard shortcut from ybeltukov
Edit2: Also "ExpandSelection"

Comment: I enjoy your approach with `NotebookApply` (+1). Do you know how to modify it for cases 2 and 3 in my answer?

Comment: @ybeltukov No, having trouble with `SelectionMove`. I think I'll add a check and only use `SelectionMove` if `den == {}`

Comment: @ybeltukov Now it works as it should, where did you find out about MenuEvaluator? Without it I couldn't use `If`

Comment: @ybeltukov Any ideas how to make things like `f[x]` work? Currently only `]` is selected

Comment: I could do nothing, until I accidentally came across [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15464/4678). Then I found many other examples: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=KeyEvent+MenuEvaluator

Comment: There are many other bad examples: `(a+b)`,`a^b`, `a@b`, `f[x][y]`, ...

Comment: I found fully compatible method, see my update.

Comment: @ssch Doesn't work at all for me, I always get this no matter if I have selected something: http://i.tyilo.com/YR6ZL.png

Comment: @ssch Nevermind it actually works, but ybeltukov's version is better.